# How to integrate OCR with Expo

Tags: react-native, expo, ocr, scanning

I tried using various libraries such as `react-native-tesseract` `react-native-text-detector` in Expo in order to integrate OCR but they did not work. This is my code and I am wondering how to integrate OCR within it. Thank you in advance for solutions!

```
  takePicture = async () => {
    if (this.camera) {
      const options = { quality: 0.5, base64: true };
      const data = await this.camera.takePictureAsync(options);
      this.runOcr(data.uri);
    }
  };

  runOcr = async (imageUri) => {
    //code here
  };
    return (
      <>
        <Camera
          ref={(ref) => {
            this.camera = ref;
          }}
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            position: "absolute",
            width: "100%",
            height: "100%",
          }}
          type={Camera.Constants.Type.back}
          autoFocus={Camera.Constants.AutoFocus.on}
          flashMode={
            !this.state.isFlash
              ? Camera.Constants.FlashMode.off
              : Camera.Constants.FlashMode.on
          }
        />
        <View
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            bottom: "5%",
            display: "flex",
            alignItems: "center",
            justifyContent: "space-between",
            width: "100%",
            flexDirection: "row",
          }}
        >
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.takePicture}>
            <Image
              style={{ width: 90, height: 90 }}
              source={require("./assets/rec.png")}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </>
    );
```

runOcr is the function where OCR happens however I removed the OCR code.

Comment: You want text data from an image file or network image - Am I right?

Comment: I also need this answer. Kindly tell

Comment: @VickyAhuja, sorry for the late response, I want it from an image file or a network image, you are correct.